Placing text in align environment results in overflowing equations on other lines
I am facing difficulty in keeping the first two equations (first line) inside the page:
  \begin{align*}
  \mathcal{F}(u)&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-i2\pi ux}dx \quad & %\text{; }
  f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathcal{F}(u)e^{i2\pi ux}du \\
  f(x) &\Leftrightarrow \mathcal{F}(u) \\
  x&= &\text{spatial coordinates (or continuous periodic variable, $t$)} \\
  \end{align*}

This results in:

  \begin{align*}
  \mathcal{F}(u)&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-i2\pi ux}dx \quad & %\text{; }
  f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathcal{F}(u)e^{i2\pi ux}du \\
  f(x) &\Leftrightarrow \mathcal{F}(u) \\
  x&= \text{spatial coordinates (or continuous periodic variable, $t$)} \\
  \end{align*}

Or, if I try the code above, then:

The following indicates that the line environment is the problem.
  \begin{align*}
  \mathcal{F}(u)&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-i2\pi ux}dx \quad & %\text{; }
  f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathcal{F}(u)e^{i2\pi ux}du \\
  f(x) &\Leftrightarrow \mathcal{F}(u) \\
  %x&= \text{spatial coordinates (or continuous periodic variable, $t$)} \\
  \end{align*}


How do I keep the equation in the other line, along with the text in the next line?
I saw but haven't tried Aligning multiple lines of text in an align environment, thinking I probably do not need to add another align environment.

You can also use \rlap to allow the text to overllap the second column.

Just drop the alignment tab & in the second equation on the first line; it's not needed.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \mathcal{F}(u) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{-i 2 \pi u x} \, \mathrm{d}x 
    \qquad
    f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathcal{F}(u) e^{i 2 \pi u x} \, \mathrm{d}u \\
  f(x) &\Leftrightarrow \mathcal{F}(u) \\
  x &= \text{spatial coordinates (or continuous periodic variable, $t$)}
\end{align*}

\end{document}

However, you may also just want to write the conditions for x as part of the text:

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{gather*}
  \mathcal{F}(u) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{-i 2 \pi u x} \, \mathrm{d}x 
    \qquad
    f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathcal{F}(u) e^{i 2 \pi u x} \, \mathrm{d}u \\
  f(x) \Leftrightarrow \mathcal{F}(u)
\end{gather*}
where $x$ is the spatial coordinates (or continuous periodic variable,~$t$) \dots

\end{document}


Special thanks for showing the right things to use, e.g. \mathrm{d}x in stead of dx!

@massisenergy It's personal choice, just be consistent (and use italic).

You may want the second line to have f(x) aligned with its right edge and \mathcal{F}(u) aligned with its left edge to the integrals above them.
You can realize this with alignedat. The explanation about x can be centered below.
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\cF}{\mathcal{F}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Fourier transform}

\begin{gather*}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
  \cF(u) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{-i 2 \pi u x} \, dx &&&
  f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cF(u) e^{i 2 \pi u x} \, du \\
  f(x) &\Leftrightarrow{} && \cF(u)
\end{alignedat}
\\
  x = \text{spatial coordinates (or continuous periodic variable, $t$)}
\end{gather*}

\end{frame}

\end{document}


You may also want to use a proper sans serif math font, but this requires LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX. Here I use Fira Sans with its companion font Fira Math; unfortunately, this font lacks the script F, but it's not difficult to replace it.
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{Fira Sans}
\setmathfont{Fira Math}
% Fira Math lacks U+2131 :-(
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[range=\mscrF,Scale=MatchUppercase]
\setmathfont[range=]{Fira Math}

\newcommand{\cF}{\mscrF}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Fourier transform}

\begin{gather*}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
  \cF(u) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{-i 2 \pi u x} \, dx &&&
  f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cF(u) e^{i 2 \pi u x} \, du \\
  f(x) &\Leftrightarrow{} && \cF(u)
\end{alignedat}
\\
  x = \text{spatial coordinates (or continuous periodic variable, $t$)}
\end{gather*}

\end{frame}

\end{document}



useful tips! I use XeLaTeX. And you're right that I'm trying it in Beamer :D
